# library for beam tracing (beam intersection) on a 3D Polygon model

Tags: opengl, 3d, intersection, trace, raytracing

I want to simulate a laser scanner which emits laser beam onto a 3D model to measure distance or other features from the model. The 3D model consists of vertices in xyz coordinate and faces; each vertex has also some user defined features.

The method should be simple. I define a view point and view vector (i.e. laser beam); what I need to do is checking the first vertex or the first face which is intersected with the view vector, then I can measure the distance and evaluate feature from the nearest vertices.

Is there any available library or tools to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is, in a very literal sense, [ray tracing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ray_tracing_%28graphics%29). The maths and code behind doing this is not particularly complicated, especially if you don't have to consider reflections. There's a tutorial for doing exactly this in C++ [here](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/raytracing_series/part1.php); triangle intersection is almost as simple as sphere intersection, and you can completely ignore the surface properties. If you don't want to write your own code (but seriously, it's maybe a hundred lines to do what you're looking for), there's a hint as to how to get Povray to do what you're after [here](http://news.povray.org/povray.advanced-users/thread/%3Cweb.4a04384f3a6933703f8cf8140@news.povray.org%3E/).

EDIT: More maths, including triangle intersection, is [here](http://www.devmaster.net/articles/raytracing/).

Comment: thanks, btw, I would like to try [bullet](www.bulletphysics.com/) as well.

Comment: That's waaaaay overkill. While you could probably find a way to do it in Bullet, it's actually designed to solve a completely different problem.

Comment: i see. I need to deal with meshes with almost million vertices. It would be impractical to implement ray casting by myself.

Comment: I think you're talking about a big problem, not a hard one. What sort of speed do you need to achieve?  How fast to you need to scan your half-million triangles?  How many rays do you actually need to cast?